# Toggle highlight while searching in Vim

Tags: vim

I like highlighting while searching in vim. Here's what I want:

I search for a word with `/`

Then, all of the results are highlighted. If I press any key other than `n` or `N`, I want the highlighting to be toggled off.

If I press `n` or `N` again after any number of commands, I want to toggle on the highlighting.

Where do I start? I'm not even sure what to google.

Comment: Don't use google, use `:help`.

Comment: I use this mapping: `nnoremap ,h :set hls!<CR>`  to toggle highlight.  I don't know if this suffice to solve your needs. But I think that most of the time, the sneak.vim plugin for sure will be enough for it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have this in my .vimrc

```
nnoremap <CR> :noh<CR>
```

so that when I'm done seeing the highlighting, I just hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to remove it. It stays gone until I hit <kbd>n</kbd> or <kbd>N</kbd> again.

**Note:** If you want to keep the functionality of <kbd>enter</kbd>, add another `<CR>` on the end of the command.

Comment: You can always remap some key you aren't using for anything else.  It can be a sequence.  I suggest the two-key sequence `gn` as I don't believe that is in use for anything by default in vim, but you could also use a function key or some other single key of your choice.  By default, the enter key moves a line down and I do use it sometimes.

Comment: I find `<cr>` to be rather nice when making macros as it goes to the start of the next line. Better than doing `j^` in my opinion. So if you do use this mapping i would highly suggest add the extra `<cr>` at the end as the note describes.

Answer (score 2):

I remap control-l (lower case L) so that it clears the search result as well as repaints the screen. This line in `.vimrc` does it:

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-l> :nohl<CR><C-l>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manually disable the last highlight with `nohl`.

I will let you know if I can figure out how to automate this.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to setup a toggle mapping.  These are some toggle mappings I have in my .vimrc:

```
let mapleader="\\"
noremap <silent> <Leader>th :set invhls hls ?<CR>
noremap <silent> <Leader>tn :set invnumber number ?<CR>
noremap <silent> <Leader>ts :set invspell spell ?<CR>
noremap <silent> <Leader>tw :set invwrap wrap ?<CR>
```

To toggle highlighting just type `\th` for toggle hls.  The others are `line number`, `spell checking`, `line wrapping`.  The final `hls ?` will display the new mode.

Comment: It is not a good habit to use shortcuts that add arbitrary abstraction and end up clogging up your head and config file with useless new variables. Don't use `invhls`, just do things the right way like this : `:set hlsearch!` `:set number!` etc..

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this, because to me it is nothing but natural.

Start searching with `/<pattern>` and once done, simply type `<Leader>/` to stop the highlighting.

`nnoremap <silent> <Leader>/ :set nohl<CR>`